# Three JS box3 from object is wrong after rotation

Tags: three.js

i have a scene contains some objects, i select one of them then rotate it then test collision by thes code

```
        var firstObject = SELECTED;
        for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
            if(objects[i]!=SELECTED){
                var secondObject = objects[i];
                firstBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(firstObject);
                secondBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(secondObject);
                var collision = firstBB.isIntersectionBox(secondBB);
                if(collision){
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

the code is works fine before rotation but after rotation the bounded bos is not computed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was too facing the same issue. This is beacuse the bounding box is created without the factor of translation and rotation so the quick fix for this is try to apply the matrix operation on the Mesh before computing the setFromObject like:

```
    firstObject.updateMatrix(); 
    firstObject.geometry.applyMatrix( firstObject.matrix );
    secondObject.updateMatrix(); 
    secondObject.geometry.applyMatrix( secondObject.matrix );
    firstBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(firstObject);
    secondBB = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(secondObject);
    var collision = firstBB.isIntersectionBox(secondBB);
```