# Get the bounding box of a rotated object

Tags: three.js

I want to get the exact rotated bounding box of an object after rotate it to make a collision detection between two objects.
i use `setFromObject` of the `THREE.Box3` but if the object rotated the bounding box after rotation does not rotate with the object.

the question which is asked before does not has an answer so i asked again to have one and i did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Three JS box3 from object is wrong after rotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228776/three-js-box3-from-object-is-wrong-after-rotation)

Comment: the other question has no answer so i had to ask another one so i get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounding box in Three.js seems axis aligned: http://3dengine.org/i/bounding.jpg.

Maybe you can use a BoxGeometry and make the collision building a plane equation with the faces normal and check points front or back side.